# Loop and update string in Django logging

Tags: python, django, logging

I am struck in syntax, I want to log using Django `logging`. I have `node_children` as a query set, and i want to log it as `comma_separated_product_id_list` by iterating over it.

```
logger.info(
    "Updated food for [{node_id}] children: [{comma_separated_product_id_list}]", 
     node_id=unicode(node.id),
     comma_separated_product_id_list=unicode(node_children)
  )
```

Suggestions?

Comment: instead of just saying `node_children` as an argument, have you tried giving it as a keyword argument like this: `comma_separated_product_id_list=node_children`?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I updated the question. @Sevanteri My questions is, how can i iterate over the queryset to to log comma separated children ids?

Comment: Ah, right. You might be able to just do `", ".join(node_children)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as a piece of cake.
`", ".join(node_children)`

## Fix

```
logger.info(
    "Updated food for [{node_id}] children: [{comma_separated_product_id_list}]", 
     node_id=unicode(node.id),
     comma_separated_product_id_list=", ".join(node_children)
  )
```